# Apply function to each row of data.frame and preserve column classes

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I wonder if there is a way to apply a function to each row of a data.frame such that the column classes are preserved? Let's look at an example to clarify what I mean:

```
test <- data.frame(startdate = as.Date(c("2010-03-07", "2013-09-13", "2011-11-12")),
                   enddate = as.Date(c("2010-03-23", "2013-12-01", "2012-01-05")),
                   nEvents = c(123, 456, 789))
```

Suppose I would like to expand the data.frame `test` by inserting all days between `startdate` and `enddate` and distribute the number of events over those days. My first try to do so was this:

```
eventsPerDay1 <- function(row) {
    n_days <- as.numeric(row$enddate - row$startdate) + 1
    data.frame(date = seq(row$startdate, row$enddate, by = "1 day"),
               nEvents = rmultinom(1, row$nEvents, rep(1/n_days, n_days)))
}

apply(test, 1, eventsPerDay1)
```

This, however, is not possible because `apply` calls `as.matrix` on `test` and thus it gets converted to a character matrix and all column classes are lost.

I already found two workarounds which you can find below, so my question is more of a philosphical nature.

```
library(magrittr)
############# Workaround 1
eventsPerDay2 <- function(startdate, enddate, nEvents) {
    n_days <- as.numeric(enddate - startdate) + 1
    data.frame(date = seq(startdate, enddate, by = "1 day"),
               nEvents = rmultinom(1, nEvents, rep(1/n_days, n_days)))
}

mapply(eventsPerDay2, test$startdate, test$enddate, test$nEvents, SIMPLIFY = F) %>%
    do.call(rbind, .)


############# Workaround 2
seq_along(test) %>%
    lapply(function(i) test[i, ]) %>%
    lapply(eventsPerDay1) %>%
    do.call(rbind, .)
```

My "problem" with the workarounds is the following:

- Workaround 1: It may not be the best reason, but I simply do not like `mapply`. It has a different signature than the other `*apply` functions (as the the order of arguments differs) and I always feel that a `for` loop would just have been clearer.
- Workaround 2: While being very flexible, I think it is not clear at first sight what is happening.

So does anyone know a function whose call would look like `apply(test, 1, eventsPerDay1)` and that will work?

Comment: If you want to preserve the class, use `lapply` looping over the sequence of rows and not `apply`

Comment: @akrun thanks for the suggestion, but isn't that exactly what I did in "workaround 2"? If not please elaborate what you mean. Thanks!

Comment: yes, you are right about that.  I posted a solution using `data.table`.  Please check if that makes it any better

Comment: Workaround 1 is best. `apply()` is meant to work with matrices (and if you pass in a data.frame, it's converted via `as.matrix`) and matrices can only have one atomic data table. Do not use `apply()` with `data.frames`.

Answer (score 2):

We can do this with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
res <- setDT(test)[,n_days := as.numeric(enddate - startdate) + 1 
           ][, .(date = seq(startdate, enddate, by= "1 day"),
          nEvents = c(rmultinom(1, nEvents, rep(1/n_days, n_days)))),
        by =  1:nrow(test)][, nrow := NULL]
str(res)
#Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  152 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ date   : Date, format: "2010-03-07" "2010-03-08" "2010-03-09" "2010-03-10" ...
# $ nEvents: int  5 9 7 11 6 6 10 7 12 3 ...
```

The above can be wrapped in a function

```
eventsPerDay <- function(dat){  
      as.data.table(dat)[, n_days:= as.numeric(enddate - startdate) + 1
       ][, .(date = seq(startdate, enddate, by= "1 day"),
    nEvents = c(rmultinom(1, nEvents, rep(1/n_days, n_days)))) , 1:nrow(dat)
        ][, nrow := NULL][]
  }

eventsPerDay(test)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another idea:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

test %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  group_by(startdate) %>%
  complete(startdate = seq.Date(startdate, enddate, 1), nesting(id)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(nEvents = rmultinom(1, first(nEvents), rep(1/n(), n()))) %>%
  select(startdate, nEvents)
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [152 x 3]
#Groups: id [3]
#
#      id  startdate nEvents
#   <int>     <date>   <int>
#1      1 2010-03-07       6
#2      1 2010-03-08       6
#3      1 2010-03-09       6
#4      1 2010-03-10       7
#5      1 2010-03-11      12
#6      1 2010-03-12       5
#7      1 2010-03-13       8
#8      1 2010-03-14       5
#9      1 2010-03-15       5
#10     1 2010-03-16       9
## ... with 142 more rows
```

Answer (score 2):

I have asked myself the same question.

I either end up splitting the df into a list (the base way)

```
xy <- data.frame()
xy.list <- split(xy, 1:nrow(xy))
out <- lapply(xy.list, function(x) ...)
answer <- unlist(out)
```

or try the hadleyverse dplyr way using rowwise (the blackbox way)

```
xy %>%
rowwise() %>%
mutate(newcol = function(x) ....)
```

I agree that their should be a base implementation of apply(xy, 1, function(x)) that doesn't coerce into character, but I imagine the R ancients implemented the matrix conversion for an advanced reason my primitive mind can't understand.